# Why does this lock change affect JDBC performance so much?

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

Im writing a database connection pool for use in a large multi threaded application, written to target jdk4 standards, with the following code I can query a mysql database over a LAN 1000 times in 0.4 seconds with my test case.

```
synchronized(lockA) {
    if(free.size() > 0) {
        c = (Connection) free.removeFirst();
    }

    if(c == null) {
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(query, name, passw);
    }
}
```

here lockA protects the free list (LinkedList), it used where the list is modified and accessed. It made sense to move the getConnection out of this lock and into its own protected block. The getConnection needs to be protected by a lock because somewhere it is not thread safe.

So if I change it so the DriverManager and the list are protected by separate locks, like so.

```
synchronized(lockA) {
    if(free.size() > 0) {
        c = (Connection) free.removeFirst();
    }
}

if(c == null) {
    synchronized(lockB) {
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(query, name, passw);
    }
}
```

I get continual cache misses (C is null) and so performance is reduced such that it takes 4 seconds to do the same query which took 0.4 seconds.

Why is this the case?

EDIT:

I have solved this, the problem arises from the way the function blocks when too many connections are created.

This is what was happening, at the start of the function.

```
synchronized(waitLocK) {
    try {
        while(count >= limit) {
            waitLock.wait();
        } 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

waitLock is released when a connection is released. But what was happening here is that after the code block to create a connection the count variable (volatile) is incremented.

This had the effect of opening the gates because when the 1000 threads tried to go through the wait test they all passed because count was still 0, then overloading the getConnection().

Moving the count++ to be after the try solves this problem.

Comment: Sorry yes C is local to the function.

Comment: "Im writing a database connection pool".... what the heck for? There are several open-source ones you can use. It's a hard problem to solve, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @skaffman: especially since there is a new kid on the block which is optimized for multi-core systems: http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=63543

Answer (score 0):

The second form of your code allows an unlimited number of threads to simultaneously request a connection to the database, where the first only allows one thread at a time to request a new connection.

When writing concurrent code in Java, I have a simple rule to follow:

If your code has the synchronized keyword in it, it's probably wrong, and will fail in subtle and unpredictable ways.

Joking aside, you need to think long and hard about why you can't achieve the concurrent result you want with a standard concurrency class.

skaffman's comment is correct -- you really don't want to implement a connection pool. Pick any one of the available implementations.

Let's say this wasn't a connection pool, though. Why use a synchronize + LinkedList, instead of ConcurrentLinkedQueue? Your logic tries to grab a connection from the list; if no connection is available, it creates a fresh connection (which, presumably, the caller will release back to the list when it's done with it).

[Java Concurrency In Practice](http://jcip.net/) is a fantastic book, if you haven't read it.